# Where are the dependencies provided by --packages option stored?

Tags: apache-spark

Where the dependencies provided by `--packages` option in `spark-submit` being stored? I did not manage to find those on workers. I am running spark submit in standalone cluster with client deploy mode.

Also I'd like to know if there is a possibility to load dependency from scratch? Seems, Spark cached my custom library, I'd like to not modify the version, but download the same version from scratch.

Comment: In which folder did you look?

Comment: I already fixed that. The .ivy2 and .m2 folders on machine which runs driver program.

Comment: You already fixed what?